# Keras Callback to save all the values of each batch per epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to gather all the values during training for each epoch. When using the `fit` function of tensorflow I only receive the last value after run through all batches. One of my ideas would be to use `GradientTape` for this but maybe there is a easier way to do so using a callback. Does anybody have an idea how to obtain the store the result for each batch?

Comment: Do you mean weights of model by _values_?

Comment: sorry I mean of getting the values of the metric (for instance accuracy) after each run/batch within an epoch.

Answer (score 1):

The [checkpoint callback](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/) may provide what you want. The `monitor` parameter allows you to specify which metrics to report and the `save_freq` parameter specifies the frequency. The latter defaults to `epoch`, but you can specify an integer instead, which specifies the number of batches between checkpoints. The object returned by the fit method includes a `history` attribute that contains the metrics at each checkpoint.